# Animating a view to draw it from top to bottom

Tags: android, android-animation

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_vertical_line"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />
```

Given a view, that is a vertical line, how would I animate it in. drawing it from top to bottom, or vice versa? I haven't been able to find any examples like I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can for example scale your line with an Animation, something like this :

```
View view = (View) getViewById(R.id.top_vertical_line);
view.animate()
    .scaleY(...)
    .setDuration(2000)
    .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator);
```

You have to fill in the value of scaleY(...) to where you want it to animate to, or check other methods in [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html).
And perhaps you should align your View at the bottom in your xml :

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```